# TabView tabBar tint color not working as expected in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios15, swiftui-tabview, accent-color

I’m going through a Ray Wenderlich course on SwiftUI and currently working on some TabView view. The method for setting the tabBar tint color used in the course is `accentColor(_:)` which sets the tabBar tint color. However, that method is now deprecated and Apple suggests using `tint(_:)` method instead.

The problem is that this is the result when using `accentColor(_:)`:

[image]
[image]

but this is the result when using `tint(_:)`:

[image]
[image]

Clearly, `tint(_:)` method isn’t the correct way of setting the tabBar tint color so my question is does anyone know which method should I use instead as the `accentColor(_:)` method is now deprecated?

Comment: Just continue using accentColor if it fits your needs until ... `deprecated: 100000.0` version happens. :)

Comment: Yes, will do, but still I’d like to know what's the proper alternative for that method